# Why isn't my Weather Underground data not printing in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, api, parsing

I'm having an issue printing data from Weather Underground. My code works with other data sources, just not Weather Underground. I have even tried replacing the URL with actual data (i.e. https://api.wunderground.com/api/APIKEY/forecast/geolookup/forecast/q/94129.json"), but it doesn't print.

Any suggestions on what it could be?

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class APIManager {
    func weatherJSON(zip: String, completion: @escaping ([Weather]) -> Void) {
        let baseUrlString = "https://api.wunderground.com/api/APIKEY/forecast/geolookup/forecast/q/\(zip).json"

        guard let url = URL(string: baseUrlString) else { return }

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            guard error == nil, let data = data else { return }

            do {
                guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [[String: Any]] else { return }

                // MARK: Print JSON
                print(json)

                var weatherList = [Weather]()
                for item in json {
                    if let weather = Weather.create(from: item) {
                        weatherList.append(weather)
                    }
                }
                completion(weatherList)
            } catch {
                print("Uh oh. You have an error with \(zip)!")
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

EDIT: SOLVED

I have used the code posted below and am now seeing errors.

Comment: Good first step would be to stick a debug messages in all your guard statements to see if any optionals aren't unwrapping

Comment: Your `guard` statement effectively says "if there's an error, don't tell me, but just immediately return." So, change that to print the `error` before returning. Or, better, change your closure to be `([Weather]?, Error?) -> Void` so that you can inform the caller when there was an error, and it can do whatever you need in the UI to report/handle the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest changing this to report errors:

```
enum WeatherError Error {
    case badURL
    case invalidJSON
}

func weatherJSON(zip: String, completion: @escaping ([Weather]?, Error?) -> Void) {
    let baseUrlString = "https://api.wunderground.com/api/APIKEY/forecast/geolookup/forecast/q/\(zip).json"

    guard let url = URL(string: baseUrlString) else { 
        completion(nil, WeatherError.badURL)
        return
    }

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        guard error == nil, let data = data else { 
            completion(nil, error)
            return
        }

        do {
            guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [[String: Any]] else {
                completion(nil, WeatherError.invalidJSON)
                return
            }

            // MARK: Print JSON
            print(json)

            var weatherList = [Weather]()
            for item in json {
                if let weather = Weather.create(from: item) {
                    weatherList.append(weather)
                }
            }
            completion(weatherList, nil)
        } catch let parseError {
            print("Uh oh. You have an error with \(zip)!")
            if let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                print("responseString = \(responseString)")
            }
            completion(nil, parseError)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Then, when you call it, you can see what the error was

```
weatherJSON(zip: something) { weatherReports, error in
    guard let weatherReports = weatherReports, error == nil else {
        print(error)
        return
    }

    // use weatherReports here
}
```

This won't solve your problem, but it will help you diagnose what the issue is.

Comment: Thank you so much! Error messages are now displaying.